# Transactional API Patch Not Updating Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, transactional-messaging-api

We have been using the Transactional API to run a set of templates for months now with no issues, we have recently wanted to update some of the content in these templates. We have made the updates in Content Builder and use the following transactional PATCH to update, everytime we see a 200, but it doesnt seem like the changes are being reflected in the update. Am I missing something in the PATCH specific to changes in content builder?

PATCH Body:

```
{
    "status": "Active",
    "name": "my-template",
    "description": "Updated Content",
    "classification": "Default Transactional",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "cb-customerKey"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "list": "All Subscribers - 1111",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": false
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try PATCH status to "Inactive" then back to "Active"

Comment: Yup that did the trick, just updating it would make to much sense lol.

Answer (score 3):

As @EazyE stated, to update HTML content you need to first make the template inactive then PATCH again and make it active.